# How to customize headline and footline of an outer theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, beamer-metropolis

I'm using the `split` outer theme along with the `metropolis` main theme.

I'd like to remove the headline of the `split` outer theme completely (and as an aside, why does the 'Agenda' page in the example below show 'Introduction' in its headline?)? And how can I customize its footline as the following:

1. Remove the text in the left-hand part (currently showing the author name)
2. Use some arbitrary text in the right-hand right (current showing the presentation title)
3. Customize the background colors of left-hand and right-hand parts

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar,subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{split}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\setbeamertemplate{institute}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,align=left] at (-0.1,-2.6){\insertinstitute};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author Name}
\institute{Organization Name\\\\\\\\\tiny Blah blah\\\tiny \href{mailto:author@email}{author@email}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{frame}{Agenda}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Introduction
            \item Main body
            \item Conclusion
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    %---------------------------------------------------

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}{Blah Blah}
        Say Something

    \end{frame}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{frame}[standout]
        End Here
    \end{frame}

    %------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows how to clear the headline and how to change the footline template.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar,subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{split}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\setbeamertemplate{institute}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,align=left] at (-0.1,-2.6){\insertinstitute};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Clear headline template
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Change footline settings here
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamercolor{custom1}{fg=magenta,bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{custom2}{fg=cyan,bg=purple}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries, family=\ttfamily}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\textwidth, sep=0.4em]{custom1}%
        \strut
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\textwidth, sep=0.4em, right]{custom2}%
        \strut arbitrary text
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author Name}
\institute{Organization Name\\\\\\\\\tiny Blah blah\\\tiny \href{mailto:author@email}{author@email}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Agenda}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Introduction
        \item Main body
        \item Conclusion
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%---------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Blah Blah}
    Say Something

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[standout]
    End Here
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```